# copy content from table into stored procedure for backup and storage

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, backup

i've got a question about raising errors and copying the contents from a table into a stored procedure.

What i need to do is move employee information to an Archive table for storage and backup,Raise Error Messages when employee number does not exist, and only move the employee records that have no sales, currently i'm stuck on what to do after i've made sure both sale number and employee number are not null.
Here is what i have so far:

```
        Create Procedure ArchiveEmployeeTranactions 
        (
        @SaleNumber int,
        @EmployeeNumber int
        )
        AS
        SELECT     sale.employeeNumber, employee.FirstName, employee.LastName, sale.saleNumber
        FROM         employee INNER JOIN
                              sale ON employee.EmployeeNumber = sale.employeeNumber

                            IF @SaleNumber is null 
                            BEGIN
                            RAISERROR ('Please enter valid Sale Number',16,1) 
                            END

                            Else
                            BEGIN
                            IF @EmployeeNumber is null
                            RAISERROR ('Please enter Valid Employee Number',16,1)
                            END
```

Comment: why you need to first do join then check if SaleNumber or EmployeeNumber is null? what do you try to achieve is not clear

Comment: from my understanding i thought this would be correct, how would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Create Procedure ArchiveEmployeeTranactions 
        (
           @SaleNumber int,
           @EmployeeNumber int
        )
  AS
  BEGIN
        IF @SaleNumber is null 
        BEGIN
           RAISERROR ('Please enter valid Sale Number',16,1) 
        END
```

```
    Else IF @EmployeeNumber is null
       RAISERROR ('Please enter Valid Employee Number',16,1)
    END

    INSERT INTO Archive
    SELECT     sale.employeeNumber, 
               employee.FirstName, 
               employee.LastName, 
               sale.saleNumber
    FROM  employee 
    INNER JOIN sale 
    ON employee.EmployeeNumber = sale.employeeNumber
    WHERE employee.employeeNumber=@EmployeeNumber 
      and sale.saleNumber=@SaleNumber
```

END